# rails: autocomplete

Tags: ruby-on-rails

how do I create autocomplete that works exactly like how the tags work in here? (stackoverflow)?

There are autocomplete plug-ins but not ones where you can separate your tags by commas and do autocomplete for each tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the jquery autocomplete the back-end is done in PHP though you can convert it on rails

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/

Here are some demos

http://jquery.bassistance.de/autocomplete/demo/

Answer (score 1):

You'd need Token Fields

http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields